# Server API request in background with WorkManager or custom service?

Tags: android, android-service, android-workmanager, android-background

I want to run *API requests when my app is closed*. This is used by the API to query whether there are new messages for the user. Unfortunately, the description of WorkManager and Service is a bit misleading. Do I need a **WorkManager** or a **Service** (**Background Service**, **Foreground Service**). I hope that someone can help me.

Comment: Ideally, you would use Firebase Cloud Messaging or some similar push messaging system, rather than polling your server. "the description of WorkManager and Service is a bit misleading" -- what exactly is "misleading" about them? "Do I need a WorkManager or a Service (Background Service, Foreground Service)" -- most likely `WorkManager` is the correct solution, given those two options.

Comment: I don't want to resort to Firebase. My app already has a finished backend and Firebase would have to change a lot and the monthly costs would also increase for me. It is a pity that there is no example of how a simple push notification service works. For example, when a new message is displayed on Whatsapp. I do find nothing about this handles.

Comment: "My app already has a finished backend and Firebase would have to change a lot and the monthly costs would also increase for me" -- AFAIK Firebase Cloud Messaging is free. Firebase Cloud Messaging does not require that the rest of the backend use anything else from Firebase. "For example, when a new message is displayed on Whatsapp. I do find nothing about this handles" -- they use Firebase Cloud Messaging, at least on Google Play ecosystem devices.